# HTML website menu animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML:

```
<div id="menu" class="menu">
        <ul class="headlines">
            <li id="item1"onclick="checklist(this)"><button onclick="myFunction()">AA</button></li>
            <li id="item2"><button onclick="myFunction2()">A </button></li>
            <li id="item3">B      </li>
            <li id="item4">C      </li>
            <li id="item5">D      </li>
            <li id="item6">E      </li>
            <li id="item7">F      </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
lu, li{
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    height: 40px;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: right;    
    border-style: none;
}

.menu{

    width:150px;
    height: 350px;
    margin:0 auto;

}



.menu li{  
position: relative;
  top:150px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto; 
  border-style:none;  
}
```

I want to animate this menu which is centered in the middle of my website, to go to the ultimate left in this form  /  ,when clicking on one of its elements. Any help?

Comment: What are you struggling with? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You have two options: 
(A) css3 animations/transitions (B) javascript (try jQuery if you are rather new to javascript and cross-browser support stuff)

Comment: I have tried transitions, however the menu stood still and didn't move to the left

Comment: The `margin:0 auto;` is a problem here. If you set `margin-left: 300px;` for testing and then animate, this should work. But as you did not set a specific px value you can't animate it. My first solution would be to use javascript to detect the current browser-calculated margin-left and specifically set it to this value. Then animate like you did before. Doesn't seem quite elegant... Anyone in for a better idea?

Comment: However won't this affect the responsiveness of the menu when resizing the browser's window?

Comment: Yes. You gotta add a `$(window).on('resize', function(){ myFunction(); });` where `myFuncion` handles resizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick bit of Jquery which will the li that is clicked left;

```
$(".headlines li").click(function () {
    $(this).animate({left: '-300px'}, 600)
})
```

**EDIT**

To move all of them when clicking a link create the CSS below, below the normal menu CSS,

```
.menuclicked{
    position: relative;
    width:150px;
    height: 350px;
    left: -300px;
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

Then use this JQuery;

```
$(".headlines li").click(function () {
   $(".menu").addClass("menuclicked");
})
```

**EDIT 2 (Adding a delay)**

To make them go one at a time us the .delay between animations to stagger them.

```
$(".headlines li").click(function () {
            $("#item1").animate({left: '-300px'}, 600)
            $("#item2").delay(100).animate({left: '-300px'}, 600)
            $("#item3").delay(200).animate({left: '-300px'}, 600)
            $("#item4").delay(300).animate({left: '-300px'}, 600)
            $("#item5").delay(400).animate({left: '-300px'}, 600)
            $("#item6").delay(500).animate({left: '-300px'}, 600)
            $("#item7").delay(600).animate({left: '-300px'}, 600)
})
```

Comment: That's part of i want, yes it's the functionality, but upon any element selection, all elements must move together to the left in this side of a triangle / form

Comment: and upon reaching the ultimate left, take the original form |

Comment: @randy ohh you want them moving one at a time?

Comment: @randy Here's [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shootermatic/jr3Lp0ge/) based on matthew's original answer

Comment: @Dom-TaphillStudios THANK YOU, I could never work out why it wasn't working in JSFiddle, turns out I was using default pureJS Thank you, I learnt something new today

Comment: @randy was that what you was after? If so your welcome, need anymore help, make a new question and send more a link here and I will check it out. Glad I could help

Comment: @MatthewHammond yeah that was it.. I really appreciate it and i sure will, thanks.

Comment: @randy your welcome, my solution is the most elegant, but for what you want it to do, it works.